Cannot enable billing on Google Cloud Platform
This is ridiculous.
I am totally unable to do anything in GCP after creating a new account for my new company. I go to create a billing account and follow the steps, press "Start Free", and then encounter the following error:
Action unsuccessful This action couldn’t be completed. [OR_BACR2_44]
I also can't access Billing Support because when I try and raise the ticket I am told "You are not a billing administratot of any account". So I can't create a billing account, then when I try and get billing support I can't even create a support ticket?
I then try and create a regular support ticket but am then told "You do not have permission to open technical support tickets." I can't even upgrade my support to enable technical support because to do so I need a billing account.
Can anyone please point me in the right direction? This is absolutely absurd.

Revisit the welcome mail that you got after creating the new account, check to see everything is pointed to you/your company's parameter. If those checks out, forward the email to google support and ask them the question you asked here. Good luck
